# Site inside Web Tab isn't working properly in IE

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

A Web Tab is created with pointing to some specific URL. It works fantastic in FF as well as in Chrome. But IE don't want to allow me to login. However I can work with this site outside Salesforce pretty good.

I tried to create VF page and put iframe pointed to the same URL - the same situation.

Maybe there are any other options to achieve my goal?

Comment: try running IE in IE8 or IE7 mode

Comment: It works fine if the page is <html>

<H1>Testing the website in Iframe </H1>
<iframe src="http://www.xyz.com"></iframe>
 
</html> But in SF it doesn't.